# How can i migrate from SwiftUI to storyboards?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I started a project in Xcode using SwiftUI, then realized it isn’t compatible with iOS 12.

Can I remove the SwiftUI code and start using storyboards without making a new project? If so, how?

Comment: I like the answer given, but really can't agree with the comment after it. @Reedzev, see my comment in the answer. Please, if you need to target iOS 12 and are using either Xcode 10 or 11, start over. anything using `UIKit` (views, controllers, even Combine) should be able to easily be copied over, either by file or clipboard. It's a pain, but chalk it up to a mistake you'll never make again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it's strictly a compatibility issue then the answer is no. Anything you'd use to convert would also be strictly #iOS 13 compatible, sorry.

Comment: I mean, SwiftUI isn’t available on iOS 12, which I didn’t realize while starting the project. Storyboards are. I don’t want to convert anything - just to remove existing SwiftUI code (as I have only worked on a custom keyboard) and use storyboards instead. I have created an empty storyboard, but unsure what to do next to make it appear after app launch.

Comment: Oh, so you're just trying to restart basically. Just add a swift file with a viewController class in it. Go to your storyboard file, set it as initial storyboard and change it's class to match the view controller class you made— that should work.

Comment: @MichaelWells, while I agree with your answer, I'd be **extremel** careful about trying out your comment. Specifically, create two "empty" projects (one Storyboard, one SwiftUI). You'll see that the SwiftUI uses a `UIHostingController` in `scene(willConnectTo:)`, where the Storyboard app uses a key for `UIMainStoryboardFile` in `info.plist`. To say nothing about how iOS 12 projects created with Xcode 10 do not even have a `SceneDelegate`....